# Prepositions in a context

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, idioms, prepositions

What is difference exactly between the following two sentences:
 (using "to" vs "for")

1- It is rare for a family to be one and done.

2- It is rare to a family to be one and done.

Comment: 'Rare' takes 'for X to ...', not 'to X to ...'. But neither sentence here makes sense. [Meaning and usage of 'one and done'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345782/meaning-and-usage-of-one-and-done)

Comment: It's rare for a family to play basketball for a year?

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth  it just context that I heard.Any way do you mean that we use" for " because it comes after rare.